How do you persuade a browser to 'Save-as' a filename with a leading period?
Is there some way to persuade major browsers to accept a content-disposition filename with a leading period? For example, I want a browser to pop up a 'Save as' with a suggested filename of .gitconfig. The obvious answer is
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".gitconfig"
Content-Type:        application/octet-stream

(octet-stream because both Firefox and Chrome add a .txt extension for text/plain).
This doesn't work: both FF and Chrome remove the period, suggesting a filename of gitconfig (RFC6266 does state that recipients need to be aware of dots, but that's completely unnecessary here).
I've tried escaping with a \, but this is ignored in both FF and Chrome, and \\. is converted to _.. Neither browser will accept an unquoted filename, and instead suggest a filename of 'unknown'.
The Chromium sources state that RFC2047 encoding is accepted (for FF as well), so I've tried
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?iso-8859-1?Q?.gitconfig?=

And percent encoding:
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%2Egitconfig

Neither of these work, either with or without quotes around the filename.
